# Remove the "techniques" and "unexpected" tags

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

There are 157 questions tagged [techniques](/questions/tagged/techniques) and 49 tagged [unexpected](/questions/tagged/unexpected) on Stack Overflow. I think these are more meta tags that don't communicate anything useful, and I suggest that they be <strike>burninated</strike> removed with compassion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agreed, these two tags have been ... *burninated*.

[image: tag burninated]

Comment: BURNINATE IT WITH MS COMIC SANS!